# Unable to save JSX elements in local Storage

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, local-storage

i'm planning to save the **react element** in the local storage for the data persistence process but the value i'm saving in local storage differs with actual value after doing **stringify**
is this how the localstorage and stringify works or i'm doing any thing wrong ?
this is the image of my state value before setting into local storage, this one i could render the value directly in jsx

*ignore the props difference of defaultValue*

[image: this is the image]

after getting the value from local storage
[image]

here is where the react element missing , this one I couldn't

this is how i'm setting the value   `localStorage.setItem("movedElements", JSON.stringify(droppedElements));`

retrieving  `const existingElements = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movedElements"));`

any sort of help is appreciated

Comment: A react element is an instance of a specific class. When you JSON.stringify it, and then JSON.parse it out, it is no longer an instance of that class, and is thus unusable as a React element

Comment: I don't think React elements are really intended to be serialized and de-serialized. Why are you trying to store them in localstorage?

Comment: What you should be storing is information about the state and props of the instance you're trying to rebuild, so you can rebuild it from that

Comment: https://openchakra.app/ building an app like this to persist the dragged elements